# C# how to populate a crystal report using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, crystal-reports

I am tring to populate a crystal report using LINQ.

Here is my code:

```
var results = (from supp in dbdata.Suppliers select supp).ToList();
cr1.Load(@"CrystalReport1.rpt");
cr1.SetDataSource(results);
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr1;
```

When I run the application it generates an error:

> DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
 CrystalReport1 cr = new CrystalReport1();

    var results = (from supp in dbdata.tSamples
                  where supp.ID == IDNUMBER
                  select new { supp.Name, supp.Model, supp.Producer }).ToList();

    cr.SetDataSource(results);
    crystalReportsViewer1.ReportSource = cr;
```

Comment: Can you please tell us, what was the reason this code work? is it due to the list of fields in the SELECT clause?

Comment: Okay. The reason is that we can't have Nullable fields in the LINQ result. Remove them, (or change them to normal variables) then it works very well.